# Зачем нужно симметричное шифрование?

Tags: криптография

Вот,зачем использовать симметричные алгоритмы,если нам приходиться передавать ключ другой стороне?Именно,зачем их в нынешнее время использовать?Если можно спокойно работать с ассиметричными алгоритмами(RSA...)?А что нам дает,если мы  текст будем шифровать симметричным алгоритмом,а перед тем как передать текст,мы передадим ключ симметричного алгоритма другой стороне с помощью RSA.И потом передаем зашифрованный текст и другая сторона расшифровывает.

Comment: Даже при использовании ассиметричного шифрования при шифровании большого текста он шифруется симметричным методом, а вот ключ шифруется ассиметричным. Потому что ассиметричные алгоритмы очень медленные. Собственно обычный ssl (который в основе https) именно так и работает

Comment: @Mike , то есть, шифрования текста происходит симметричным шифром , а ключ асимметричным .Ага,значит это дает скорость.

Comment: По крайней мере большинство применений ассиметричных алгоритмов делают так. Даже электронные подписи документов сначала вычисляют какой нибудь хеш, а потом уже шифруют его ассиметричным способом, фактически подписывая только сам хеш. Понятно, что существуют и чисто ассиметричные и чисто симметричные схемы для различных применений

Answer (score 2):

> А что нам дает,если мы текст будем шифровать симметричным алгоритмом,а перед тем как передать текст,мы передадим ключ симметричного алгоритма другой стороне с помощью RSA.И потом передаем зашифрованный текст и другая сторона расшифровывает.

Открыли велосипед называется...

Именно так в реальной жизни и поступают. Дело в том, что асимметричное шифрование заметно уступает в скорости шифрования (примерно на порядок), зависит конечно от длины ключа и т.д., но в общем и целом картина именно такая.

Например, [почитайте как организовано шифрование в менеджере паролей от Yandex](https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/344382/) - активно применяется асимметрия и симметрия.